# Can Eigenvalues[] and Eigenvectors[] be assumed to return the same ordering?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I do back to back calls of `Eigenvalues[]` and `Eigenvectors[]` can these be assumed to order the values and vectors the same, or is each independent?

Related to this is a curiosity about the performance of a pair of calls like this.  Are Mathematica optimizations done at an expression level, or if a result from one could help another later (or previous) calculation, is it able to reorder internally and/or make use of previous calculations?

Comment: I would say it's vastly preferable to just use `{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat]` if you in fact need both.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need to be sure that the order is correct, there is a function [`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigensystem.html) that returns a list of both the eigenvalues and -vectors, which is in the right order.

```
{eValues, eVectors} = Eigensystem[{{2, 0}, {0, 1}}];
eValues
eVectors
```

> ```
> {2, 1}
> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
> ```

It's probably worth using just for the slight off-chance that `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors` do not yield the same order (not sure about whether this may or may not happen), which will be really painful to debug.

Comment: Thanks for also showing the (perl-like) syntax fragment that gives names to the parts of the list, right in the assignment.  I didn't know that was allowed and is helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. The easy way to check this is to do

```
M == Total@MapThread[#1 KroneckerProduct[#2,#2], 
          {Eigenvalues[M], Eigenvectors[M]} ]
```

it should return true.  Although, you may need to use

```
KroneckerProduct[Conjugate@#2,#2]
```

if your matrices are complex. But, as J.M. pointed out, it is preferable to use `Eigensystem`. Also, if some of your eigenvalues have multiplicities greater than 1, the corresponding eigenvectors are linearly independent, not orthogonal.

**Edit**: To orthogonalize your eigenvectors, simply use `Orthogonalize` on them. Since eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are guaranteed to be orthogonal, this won't effect the order, but will give you a reasonable subspace.

The above code is valid if the matrix, $M$, is non-defective in a numerical sense, i.e. it can't be nearly defective, such as

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 15 \\ \epsilon & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\epsilon$ is very small and close to the limits machine precision. However, if the above holds, and it barring precision problems, it holds for normal and Hermitian matrices, then the spectral decomposition is simply

$$ \mathbf{M} = \sum^N_i \lambda_i \vert \lambda_i \rangle \langle \lambda_i \vert $$

where $\vert \lambda_i \rangle \langle \lambda_i \vert$ is the outer product of the $i^\text{th}$ eigenvector with itself.

Comment: The situation is even worse if OP's matrices are defective. At the very least, if OP has Hermitian matrices, the multiple eigenvalues are not so problematic.

Comment: Proof by example isn't a very good idea if you ask me.

Comment: @David sorry, I disagree. I'm merely restating the spectral decomposition theorem, which allows you to rewrite the matrix as a sum of outer products of its eigenvectors. Yes, it requires that the matrix be non-defective, which I have added to my answer.

Comment: @David: for the Hermitian case at least, it's instructive to compare the results of `Eigensystem[]` and `SchurDecomposition[]`... :)

Comment: That makes it a proof for a special case. Assuming they're always equal because of this is quite dangerous the next time you simply use the functions the way you think they do "because it always worked".

Comment: @David: the impression I got from rcollyer and other people is that physicists pretend defective matrices don't exist... :)

Comment: @David again, I must disagree. I was lax in not specifying the conditions, yes. But, the OP's posts deal with quantum mechanics the vast majority of the time, so assuming hermiticity or normality was not an error on my part, although I should have made it clear to everyone else.

Comment: Oh, if the majority of his questions are about QM it makes sense of course. $\square$

Comment: @David don't worry about it. I assumed that the OP would understand it, but I was not thinking about everyone else.

Comment: @rcollyer "I was not thinking about everyone else" — I think it's better to write for the third person (random Googler), especially in general questions like this, so that the full context is available (they won't know that the OP's questions are generally about QM).

Comment: @R.M and I was called on it, so I corrected the issue by including the necessary conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica orders the results differently depending on what kind of data is in the matrix.

For example, 
`m = {
  {h, t, 0, t},
  {t, h, t, 0},
  {0, t, h, t},
  {t, 0, t, h}
 }`

has Eigensystem
`(h h   h-2t    h+2t
{0,-1,0,1}  {-1,0,1,0}  {-1,1,-1,1} {1,1,1,1})`

But `n = {
  {0, 1, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0},
  {0, 1, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0}
 }`

has Eigensystem
`(-2    2   0   0
{-1,1,-1,1} {1,1,1,1}   {0,-1,0,1}  {-1,0,1,0})`

Mathematica uses rows as vectors, not columns. Since I'm used to vectors being columns, I normally `Transpose[]` my new matrix of `Eigenvectors[]`. Also, depending on what you are trying to solve, you might want to `Orthogonalize[]` the eigenvectors which have degenerate eigenvalues after having `Normalize[]`'d them.

Comment: You have to use `Transpose` anyway to transform into diagonal basis. Additionally, `Orthogonalize` produces an orthonormal set of vectors, so using `Normalize` is an unnecessary additional step.