# ordering of functional eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any order to the symbolic eigenvalues of a matrix returned by the command `Eigenvalues[...]`?

While numerical eigenvalues are listed in descending order (i.e., $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_N $), this is not the case for functional eigenvalues (see two examples below). The examples suggest that the ordering may be the reverse, although this cannot be positively inferred from two examples. Do functional eigenvalues have the order $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \cdots \lambda_N$, another ordering (based on eigenvectors, for instance), or no ordering at all?

---

Examples showing that functional eigenvalues are not sorted in descending order.

(1) As a trivial example,

```
Eigenvalues[{{Exp[x], Exp[x]}, {Exp[x], Exp[x]}}]
```

returns $\left\{0,2 e^x\right\}$. For real inputs, the latter is always greater than or equal to the former.

(2) As another example, consider

```
Eigenvalues[{{Exp[x], Exp[x]}, {Exp[x], Exp[x/2]}}]
```

which returns

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{x/2}+e^x-e^{x/2} \sqrt{1-2 e^{x/2}+5 e^x}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{x/2}+e^x+e^{x/2} \sqrt{1-2 e^{x/2}+5 e^x}\right)\right\}.$$

Again, for real inputs, the latter is always greater than or equal to the former:

```
Plot[%, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1831/121

Comment: How can they have any order if they are still symbolical?

Comment: The eigenvalues are functions. But they could still have an order. For instance, $\log 3x \ge \log 2x \ge \log x$.

Comment: But what if they were `Sin[x]` and `Cos[x]`? You'd have to use `OrderedQ`, like `Sort` does, which would sort them as `{Cos[x], Sin[x]}`. But then if you define `x` to be some number, the list will not be ordered for around half the possible values of `x`.

Comment: @acl: Right, in such a case, ordering by magnitude would not make any sense. But in cases like those posited above, there is clearly a function that is greater than or equal to the other.

Answer (score 2):

My strong hunch is that when the eigenvalues cannot be treated as numbers, the eigenvalues are always ordered according to "Sort". Thus, they are sorted in MMA's "canonical" order, some of which is described in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2730/360.

For your specific example:

```
In[48]:= Sort[{Log[x], Log[2 x], Log[3 x]}]

Out[48]= {Log[x], Log[2 x], Log[3 x]}

In[49]:= Sort@Eigenvalues[{{Exp[x], Exp[x]}, {Exp[x], Exp[x/2]}}] == 
 Eigenvalues[{{Exp[x], Exp[x]}, {Exp[x], Exp[x/2]}}]

Out[49]= True
```

For mixed eigenvalues, the numeric ones are listed first:

```
In[63]:= m = ({{1000, 0, 1}, {1, Log[3 x], 0}, {0, 0, Log[2 x]}});
Eigenvalues[m]

Out[64]= {1000, Log[2 x], Log[3 x]}
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but didn't answer because I couldn't convincingly explain why this list: `{Log[x] - Exp[x], Log[99 x], Log[x]}` is sorted as `{Log[x], Log[x] - Exp[x], Log[99 x]}` — i.e., why isn't `Log[x] - Exp[x]` the last? Looking at `TreeForm`, `Length` and `LeafCount` of the list above all remain unconvincing thus far (to me)...

Comment: Well, if it compares depth first, Log[x] only has `x` at the deepest level. Then it compares `{e,x}` and `{99,x}` and `e<99` so it goes first. At least that would be my argument. But that is more of a post-hoc argument, since I thought that it compares at the same level.

Comment: But that's not what the `Sort` documentation says... it says it sorts by length _first_ and then, in case of a tie, it compares depth first. _"`Sort` usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth-first manner"_

Comment: @R.M oops missed that caveat. I guess my only defense is the "usually" in there :)

Comment: ha, that _"usually"_ is a stinker — WRI's get-out-of-jail card ;)

Comment: @R.M I need to remember to write that in any documentation. That way no-one can blame me if things go wrong

Comment: @R.M that gives a whole new meaning to *probabilistic programming*.

Answer (score 1):

From Documentation:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigenvalues.html

In the section "More information":

"If they are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value."

Even when we have "exact" form (perhaps what you mean by symbolic) the are still sorted in decreasing order:

```
m = Partition[Sin[#] & /@ Range[9], 3]; m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Eigenvalues[m] // FullSimplify // Column
```

[image]

```
In[1]:=N[%]

         0.21897
Out[1]:= 0.0756954
         0.
```

**================ Comment reply ================**

Your specific case is easy to check:

```
m = ({{Log[3 x], 0, 1},{1, Log[x], 0},{0, 0, Log[2 x]}}); m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
In[1]:= ev = Eigenvalues[m]

Out[1]= {Log[x], Log[2 x], Log[3 x]}
```

So, you see, - it does not hold. It sorts them differently.

Comment: How about for symbolic eigenvalues that are functions?

Comment: @user001: Functions of what? And what do you mean when you ask in this case about sorting in descending order?

Comment: @murray: Suppose the eigenvalues were $\log x$, $\log 2x$, and $\log 3x$. I wish to know if the order returned by Mathematica would necessarily be $\log 3x$, $\log 2x$, $\log x$.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: The example you provided is still numerical, even if it is in symbolic form.

Comment: @user001: No, expressions such as `Log[3x]` are $not$ numeric, as you can directly check by using `NumericQ`.

Comment: @murray. You need to follow the edit history of the conversation. The example I referred to in the comment addressed to VitaliyKaurov was the trigonometric one (`1/2 (Sin[1] + Sqrt[5 + 12 Cos[2] + 6 Cos[4] + 4 Cos[6] + 4 Cos[8] + 2 Cos[12]] Sin[3] + Sin[5] + Sin[9])`), which is most certainly numeric. The `Log[...]` example was one I proposed myself, and is of course non-numeric, as I pointed out in my comment addressed to you yesterday.

Comment: @murray: VitaliyKaurov added the `Log[...]` example to his answer in response to my suggestion, subsequent to my comment about the trigonometric expression being essentially numeric.