# How do I keep the right ordering of eigenvalues using Eigensystem?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm having an issue with the `Eigensystem` command. I need to diagonalize a bunch of 3 by 3 complex valued matrices, but more importantly, I need to keep the exact ordering of their eigenvalues once brought to their diagonal form.

For example, if

```
A = { {1.999, 0.000428712*I, 0} , {-0.000428712*I, 2.00072, 0} , {0, 0, -4.00057} }
```

then `Eigensystem[A]` returns the three eigenvalues (with their corresponding eigenvectors) listed in order of decreasing magnitude (absolute value).

What is even more annoying is if my loop runs into an already diagonal 3 by 3 matrix such as `B = {{2,0,0},{0,-3,0},{0,0,2}}`, it will reorder the eigenvalues as `{-3,2,2}`.

Is there a command that gives me the eigenvalue without re-sorting them?

Comment: What is it about your application that requires the order to be maintained?

Comment: No, there is no command that returns the eigenvalues in a different order.  Can you explain in exactly what order you need to have them?  Any order is equally valid, just as any reordering of one diagonal matrix is an equally valid diagonalization.  How do you define your preferred order?  You're saying "How do I keep the right ordering of eigenvalues?", but you did not explain clearly what you consider to be the "right" order.

Comment: This is [similar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/can-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-be-assumed-to-return-the-same-ordering), maybe what you're looking for?

Comment: In any event: you can use `SortBy[]` to sort your eigenpairs by whatever your sorting criterion is...

Comment: Let me clarify. All my 3*3 matrices are given WRT an identical, ordered basis set. In my case the ordering matters because it relates to a certain physical system with three energy curves. For example, if B={{2,0,0},{0,-3,0},{0,0,2}} which is already diagonal, then the first eigenvalue 2 will correspond to (x1,y1), the second to (x1,y2) and the third to (x1,y3), where y1, y2 and y3 are three points on three different energy curves (in this case two of my eigenvalues are degenerate).
If Eigensystem reorders my eigenvalues it becomes very complicated for me to tell these values apart.

Comment: @drg I understand that you just need to keep the ordering from the diagonal when you have a diagonal matrix.  But then you don't even need `Eigenvalues`, you can just use `Diagonal`.  What if you don't have a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Do you mean that you have an *almost diagonal* matrix and the off-diagonal elements are close to zero?  In that case, what if you have a near-degeneracy?  It'll introduce the same ambiguity.  If you can define the order you need precisely for the general case, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: But, `Eigensystem` tells you how it reorders `B` by giving you the eigenvectors, too.

Comment: @ Szabolcs For already diagonal matrices, Diagonal would work just fine indeed. For non diagonal matrices, there happens to be a correct ordering that matches that of the already diagonal ones (this has to do with the ordered basis set). I understand that mathematica has no way to tell what this ordering is and thus use an ordering by magnitude. Then let me put it this way: I want the eigenvalues/eigenvectors to be given in such an order so that when I build U, the diagonalizing matrix, I get: U^dagger x A x U = D, D being diagonal, and more importantly, U*D*U^dagger gives me A back.

Comment: @rcollyer you are correct, but then I would need to check which U (see above) constructed form various arrangements of these eigenvectors gives me the exact same A back when performing the reverse matrix multiplication (again, see my previous comment).

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe SchurDecomposition[matrix][[2]] will indicate the eigenvalues in the ordering you want. If so, then it should not be too difficult from there to get the corresponding eigenvectors, as delivered by Eigensystem, into the desired order.

Comment: @DanieLichtblau I think this will do the job. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Please consider turning this comment into an answer

Comment: `JordanDecomposition` might work as well.

Comment: I always use two different commands Eigenvalues[Matrix] and Eigenvectors[Matrix], so that Eigenvalues[Matrix][[i]] corresponds to Eigenvectors[Matrix][[i]]. It is a bit easier for me to work with two different lists.

Comment: @Heike: If the entries are exact numbers, Jordan works nicely. If the entries are inexact, Daniel's solution is a more stable route...

Comment: @drg: If U is an unitary matrix (are there diagonalizable matrices where it isn't?) then $U^\dagger A U = D$ already implies that $U D U\dagger = A$. Moreover, permutation matrices are unitary, therefore that condition does in no way fix an order of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @AnastasiiaAnishchenko: How is `eval=Eigenvalues[mat];evec=Eigenvectors[vec];` simpler than `{eval, evec}=Eigensystem[vec];`? The latter gives exactly the same result, but is both shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Just a guess, but maybe `SchurDecomposition[matrix][[2]]` will indicate the eigenvalues in the ordering you want. If so, then it should not be too difficult from there to get the corresponding eigenvectors, as delivered by `Eigensystem`, into the desired order.

Comment: This is not working for me. Can I get a slightly better explanation?

Comment: @Santi I'm sure the statute of limitations has expired on this, but I guess the idea was that `SchurDecomposition` would not reorder if presented with an upper triangular matrix. So the eigenvalues would be seen as just the diagonal of the input, and obtained as `Diagonal[SchurDecomposition[matrix][[2]]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Make a list of {eigenvalues, eigenvectors} and sort it with respect to the eigenvalues.

```
A = {{1.999, 0.000428712*I, 0}, {-0.000428712*I, 2.00072, 0}, {0, 
0, -4.00057}};
{eigs, vecs} = Eigensystem[A];
list1 = Partition[Riffle[eigs, vecs], 2];
list2 = Sort[list1, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]; 
list2 // MatrixForm
```

you get[image]

Comment: `SortBy[]` would be more convenient for this.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a lot of time, but I think that the following code may be usefull.

```
A = {{1.999, 0.000428712*I, 0}, {-0.000428712*I, 2.00072, 0}, {0, 
0, -4.00057}};
{eigs, vecs} = Eigensystem[A];
ord = Ordering[eigs];
eigsorted = eigs[[ord]];
vecsorted = vecs[[ord]];
{eigsorted, vecsorted}
```

you obtain

```
{{-4.00057, 1.9989, 2.00082}, {{0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 1. + 0. I}, {0. - 0.973387 I, 0.229169 + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0.229169 I, 0.973387 + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}}}
```

The result is sorted by increasing eigenvalues with its corresponding eigenvector. I use the above instruction within a module if the matrix A depends on an external parameter.