# Exploiting self-adjointness when changing basis

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am using *Mathematica* to analyze a real, self-adjoint matrix $H$ of the size $32 \times 32$, which comes from a physics problem. In the picture there is also a matrix $Q$ which commutes with $H$.

I would like to see what $Q$ looks like in the eigenbasis of $H$, and I run into some technical issues that I was hoping someone might be kind enough to resolve.

To find an eigenbasis of $H$ is not difficult - the functions `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors` work well enough. The next step is very simple in theory: combine the eigenvectors into a transition matrix $P$, and compute the matrix of $Q$ relative to the new basis as $Q' = P^{-1}Q P$. In practice, it seems that the computation of the inverse requires a lot of computation, which is time consuming now, and will probably become infeasible for larger $H$. After a moment's thought, I realized that the matters could greatly helped by the fact that $H$ is self-adjoint: it follows that it has an *orthonormal* eigenbasis, for which computing the inverse amounts to computing the adjoint. This would solve the matters if $H$ had all eigenvalues *distinct* (then $P$ mentioned above would already be self-adjoint, maybe up to re-scaling the rows), but this is not the case here.

Hence the question: Given a self-adjoint matrix $H$, together with its eigenvectors, assuming that the eigenspaces are more than $1$-dimensional, how can I effectively compute the inverse matrix? (Alternatively: how else can I find the matrix form of $Q$ relative to the eigenbasis of $H$?)

Comment: This has also been addressed in the comments and answers to [Can Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors be assumed to return the same ordering?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1831/245)

Comment: `QRDecomposition` might be useful for obtaining an orthogonal change of basis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As $P$ is explicitly constructed from eigenvectors of a self-adjoint matrix, it is unitary, i.e $P P^\dagger = I\qquad$ where the $\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose (or Hermitian conjugate, if you prefer). So, calculating the inverse is simply `ConjugateTranspose[P]` which is much faster than calculating it using `Inverse`. That said, you have to ensure that the eigenvectors are orthonormal to properly form $P$ as [`Eigenvectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigenvectors.html) only guarantees linear independence in degenerate eigenspaces. A simple example of this effect is

```
Eigensystem[#.DiagonalMatrix[{-1, 1, 1}].ConjugateTranspose[#]]& @
  RotationMatrix[2 Pi/3, {1, 0, 1}]
```

which gives

```
{{-1, 1, 1}, {{1/3, Sqrt[2/3], 1}, {-3, 0, 1}, {-Sqrt[6], 1, 0}}}
```

As you can see, in this case the eigenvectors are not normalized, nor are the eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$ orthogonal to each other. In this state, $P$ is not unitary:

```
#.ConjugateTranspose[#]& @ %[[2]]
(* {{16/9, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 3 Sqrt[6]}, {0, 3 Sqrt[6], 7}} *)
```

This must be corrected to be useful, and it can be done using [`Orthogonalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orthogonalize.html). The code is as follows:

```
P = Orthogonalize@Eigenvectors@H;
Qprime = P.Q.ConjugateTranspose[P];
```

Note, this uses $P Q P^\dagger$, instead of $P^\dagger Q P$ as `Eigenvectors` explicitly generates a matrix where the rows are the eigenvectors of $H$.

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I needed. And yes, I did mean $Q' = P^{-1} Q P$; just corrected it for increased readibility.

Comment: You're welcome. I removed the question from my answer. Incidentally, I have been bitten by the linear independence issue a number of times, and it is easy to miss being a single line under the `Details` section of the documentation.

Comment: +1. But didn't you mean to write "between nondegenerate" instead of "in degenerate"?

Comment: @whuber No, I meant "within a degenerate eigenspace," which may not be the correct term in this case. Probably, this is more correct: "between the eigenvectors for a degenerate eigenvalue."  Does that work better?

Comment: I'm not sure. Because eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix with different eigenvalues are guaranteed orthogonal, the only issue concerns within degenerate eigenspaces. The help asserts that orthonormal eigenvectors for degenerate eigenspaces are returned. That leaves me wondering why `Orthogonalize` is needed at all.  But I'm not really sure what you're saying because of the sudden mysterious appearance of "$U$" in your answer.

Comment: @whuber But, the algorithm used by `Eigenvector` only guarantees linear independence for the eigenvectors of a degenerate eigenvalue. For example, with `Eigensystem[#.DiagonalMatrix[{-1,1,1}].ConjugateTranspose[#]]& @ RotationMatrix[2 Pi/3, {0,0,1}]` you'll note the eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$ are not normalized, and for more complex cases, they won't be orthogonal, either. Hence, the need for `Orthogonalize`, and it is just simpler to apply it to the entire basis, instead of trying to pick out the degenerate spaces.

Comment: @whuber (cont'd) as to the use of $U$, simply a common notation for a unitary matrix. But, I can see where it is misleading.

Comment: @whuber I clarified the text a bit to highlight the issues, alongside finding an example which shows orthogonality between eigenspaces, but not within the degenerate space.