# Order of eigenvectors

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix

```
A = {{5, 4, 2}, {4, 5, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}
```

The eigenvalues  are `1, 1, 10` and I need to find the eigenvectors.

Solving for `1` would result in two eigenvectors.
Using *WolframAlpha* I get `(-1, 0, 2)` and `(-1, 1, 0)`

This comes from `x3 = -2 (x1 + x2)`

For instance I could have:

> ```
> x1 = 1, x2 = -1, x3 = 0
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> x1 = -1, x2 = 1, x3=0
> ```

and

> ```
> x1 = 0, x2 = -1, x3 = 2
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> x1=-1, x2=0, x3=2
> ```

How to properly order those values?

Comment: I believe this was already answered here: [(1831)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1831).  Therefore I am closing this question.  If anyone feels that I am in error please tell me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem correctly.

Anyway, use `Eigensystem` to find Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors at the same time.

Here we go

```
A = {{5, 4, 2}, {4, 5, 2}, {2, 2, 2}};

Eigensystem[A]

(* {{10, 1, 1}, {{2, 2, 1}, {-1, 0, 2}, {-1, 1, 0}}} *)
```

Hence the Eigenvalues are `{10,1,1}` and the respective Eigenvectors appear ordered lexicogaphically in the list `{{2, 2, 1}, {-1, 0, 2}, {-1, 1, 0}}`.

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Using `Eigensystem` will give a unique ordering, but that avoids the underlying question.  The set of eigenvectors for a matrix is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that by definition, an eigenvalue is only unique up to a scalar: `Ax=λx`, but you can multiply x by any scalar `b` and still have an eigenvector.  This is the difference between the first two eigenvectors you've proposed ({1, -1, 0} and {-1, 1, 0}).

The second part is that when you have a repeated eigenvalue, there may be a space of independent eigenvectors.  Here, any other linear combination of the eigenvectors you've proposed (such as {-1, -1, 4}) is a valid eigenvector.  The important requirement for the second eigenvector is that it be linearly independent from the first.  It's not a matter of picking the eigenvector that is right, it's a matter of picking one that is convenient.  Often, we'll select it to be orthogonal.

Eigenvectors are ordered based on the values of their corresponding eigenvalues.  I am unfamiliar with any convention for ordering eigenvectors corresponding to repeated eigenvalues.